# POCO classes and Stable Abstraction Principle

Tags: architecture, clean-architecture

When calculating **The Abstraction Index**, defined as `A = Na / Nb` where (`Na` is the number of interfaces and abstract classes where `Nb` is the number of concrete classes), how POCO classes should be taken into account?

This classes does not implement any logic but they are only containers for data.

The risk is that a library with a high number of POCO would be rated very low on the abstraction classes but does not implement any logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if an object does not contain any logic it can be very concrete. In fact if you think about data transport objects which transport data for a concrete use case (e.g. a ContactFormRequest send from contact page of a web site)  or DTOs which contain data of a data source (e.g. a CustomerAddress representing a database table row), those objects are very concrete in terms of business rules and intended use. A requirement change can easily impact such objects.

Those objects should rather be counted to Nb in the formula above.